# reduce JS execution time with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, pagespeed, lighthouse

I have a website that I'm trying to optimize lighthouse page speed ranking. I just switched from SSR with nginx caching to `next export` using `exportPathMap` and `getInitialProps` (also with nginx caching).

Specific page of interest gets heavy traffic

After switching to static, the first content image appears loads in 2-2.5s for "slow 3G". However JS execution time takes like 3-6 seconds.

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Why does script evaluation take 3-6s when I am using a static export, I was under the impression it would be quite fast?
2. Are there ways to optimize nextjs JS execution time? Or maybe a webpack setting?

Comment: When I open that page with javascript disabled I do get all the content, scripts are loaded and executed before the user can interact with the page but all static html content seems to be there on initial load.

Comment: Maybe trying lazy import some modules that you know that could be really big so your users can have a lower script evaluation. I would also suggest some audits through profiling dev tools.

Comment: I assume this includes all the additional ad serving scripts right?

Comment: Yes this includes the ad serving scripts, those are going to slow the page, not much I can do about it. @HMR I did add lazy loading on everything but the rewriter section and it didn't make any different, I think it's just the rewriter section logic. I'll see if I can lazy load parts of it, not sure if lazy loading is supported for static export, worth looking into.

Comment: Want to try using lazyload?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try wrapping some heavy modules like this:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Spinner } from './spinner';

const MyLazyLoadedHeavyComponent = dynamic(() => import('./my-heavy-component'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <Spinner />
});

export const MyQuicklyLoadingPage: FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the page!</h1>
      <p>You'll see this text</p>
      <p>Before we load the heavy stuff below</p>
      <p>Large markdown files containing lots of images, etc.</p>
      <MyLazyLoadedHeavyComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I also use this sometimes for modules that can't be rendered with SSR.

Also, evaluate whether something like attempting to use Preact will improve performance. I don't know how easy to do that is with nextJS. I found this https://github.com/developit/nextjs-preact-demo

Comment: Hey Charley, I accepted since the bounty only has 30 minutes left, but it doesn't actually help me too much. I've actually used this dynamic set up without success on 90% of the application, i'm going to attempt to use it on the 10% of the heavier part and see what happens. As for preact, I have considered, but I have some complex hook logic in some locations that I don't believe is supported from preact, specifically on one page. My pages are completely static and the logic is only run when you're using a text input area which shouldn't be too heavy. Any other suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: Saddly I tried to improve it with this, and nothing :( I set most of the page to ssr false with next export without success :( It did reduce my JS size, but time didn't change much.

Comment: @KevinDanikowski did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Mayank-Dolphin nope :/ I implemented static export without success. I haven't tried `useStaticProps` yet which I plan to try in the future.

Comment: What is `<PreDynamicState />` referring to?

Comment: @Steve Its the loading state component. I renamed `<PreDynamicState />` to `<Spinner />` to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this suggestion](https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/improve/dynamic-imports) by Next.js? I think it's exactly your case.

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Country search..."
  className={styles.input}
  onChange={async e => {
    const { value } = e.currentTarget
    // Dynamically load libraries
    const Fuse = (await import('fuse.js')).default
    const _ = (await import('lodash')).default

    const fuse = new Fuse(countries, {
      keys: ['name'],
      threshold: 0.3
    })

    const searchResult = fuse.search(value).map(result => result.item)

    const updatedResults = searchResult.length ? searchResult : countries
    setResults(updatedResults)

    // Fake analytics hit
    console.info({
      searchedAt: _.now()
    })
  }}
/>
```

Comment: what's the difference between this and next Dynamic, seems to be the same intentions except that Fuse can be used even later